# LinkedIn share button not sharing URL

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn share button to share my URL. Here is the code for that :

```
<!-- LinkedIn Share Button -->
<!-- https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator -->

<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right" data-showzero="true" data-counter="right" data-url="http://www.myurl.com/<?php echo $url->short; ?>"></script>`
```

Couple of issues i am facing with this:

1. The shared URL does not have any title which i have stored in $url->title[1] variable.
2. Shared URL is picking up link from the page where it is placed, instead of using $url->short

Comment: Are the values of `$url->title` and `$url->short` correct before dumping them in? Fancy showing us the front end (right click, view source) output of the following line? 
`<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right" data-showzero="true" data-counter="right" data-url="http://www.myurl.com/<?php echo $url->short; ?>"></script>`

Comment: Yes, $url->short/title works for other connectors for Facebook and Twitter

Comment: Where is `$url->title` actually used though? Can't see it above in your code.

Comment: I have no clue where i can use it. The documentation at https://developer.linkedin.com/share-plugin-reference does not help.

Comment: You're setting the title but not actually passing it to the script it seems. The JS might pull the current page's URL/Title automatically in that case. 

First try putting `data-url="http://www.google.com"` first in the string, right after:

    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US
    </script>
    <script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://www.google.com" data-counter="right">
    </script>

I've just tried that and it works. Hardcode

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn now supports using `og:` tags to set the preview display values of `title`, `description`, `image`, etc..

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article' />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Share Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

If you're not sure how it's trying to pick up or share your URL, test your URL at the **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**.  Insert your URL here (`example.com`), not the URL you are going to share with (`linkedin.com?url=example.com`).

Here are two good example sites: Wikipedia (with a description) and GitHub (with an image):

[image]
[image]

- [Share GitHub](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F)
- [Share WikiPedia](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F)

Just inspect the HTML source of their main pages, and the `og:` usually stand out right away at the top of the `<head>` block -- it's important to be shared correctly these days, that's for sure!